# Get ALL view inside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, view

I am trying to get all views inside my UIViewController.

I am using this code:

```
    for subview : UIView in self.view.subviews{
        //code here
    }
```

the problem is that I don't get views that are inside a UIView.
so I get all view except of their children.

please, how can I get ALL Views that are either child or parent inside my UIViewController? even if a view has a child that has a child that has a child. I want to go through all views.

thanx in advance :)

(please in swift 4.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to recursively process all subviews.

```
func processSubviews(of view: UIView) {
    // 1. code here do something with view
    for subview in view.subviews {
        // 2. code here do something with subview
        processSubviews(of: subview)
        // 3. code here do something with subview
    }
    // 4. code here do something with view
}
```

You need to put your code at either position 1, 2, 3, or 4 (or possibly two or more of those places) depending on the results you want.

Then you can call this as:

```
processSubviews(of: self.view)
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked. now I can resize all views via code very easily :)

Answer (score 0):

For get all views (as Label, Button, View, ...) in your view hierarchy and access to all child view in your viewController you should using from a recursive func to iterate all views :

```
func getAllSubviews(view:UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let takenLabel = subview as? UILabel {
            takenLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        getAllSubviews(view:subview)
    }
}
```

You can using from this func to access other view like button and change them .

in this case i'm changing background color of all label in viewController to red

Answer (score 0):

## There are many different way to get subviews

To Get all the subviews in the parent view

```
for subview in view.subviews{

      // you can get all of your views one by one here.
}
```

To Filter if any tagged view is available or not (lets assume view is tagged by 100)

```
        view.subviews.filter{$0.tag == 100}
```

Extensions to check if Any view contains sub views

```
extension UIView{

    func isAvailabletoParentView(inParentView : UIView, subViewTag : Int) -> Bool{

        var isAvailable = false

        for subviews in inParentView.subviews{

            if subviews.tag == subViewTag{

                isAvailable = true
                return true
            }else{

                isAvailable = false
            }
        }
        return isAvailable
    }
}
```

Call Extension like

```
subview.isAvailabletoParentView(inParentView: parentView, subViewTag: anyTagToSubView)
```

Hope it will helps , Happy coding .